# I trying to create event for clear new bot perms when they join the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event

async def on_member_join(member):

    if member.bot:

        perms=discord.Permissions()

        perms.update(permissions = PermissionOverwrite)

    await member.edit(reason='New bot joined')
```

I do not understand what exactly it takes for the event to work, in other cases it either gives an error or simply does not work

I tried

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.bot:
        perms=discord.Permissions()
        perms.update(permissions = PermissionOverwrite)
    await member.edit(permissions=perms, reason='New bot joined')
```

but this gives the error that `member.edit` cannot have `perms/permissions`

Comment: Tut tut. read docs. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.edit

member edit does not have a permission attribute. you will need to edit the role itself

Comment: I already understand this, but thanks for answer